# Read and Write all bytes of/in a file in Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, file, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I need to read all bytes of a file and write this byte array to another file. I.e. I need the same behavior of [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in Windows Mobile 6.1.

What is the fastest method to do this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need the whole file in memory at any time? If not, I'd just use something like:

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024]; // Or whatever size you want
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Then just open each file accordingly:

```
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(...), output = File.OpenWrite(...))
{
    CopyStream(input, output);
}
```

Comment: Random aside: while I've seen it in the spec, I'm not sure I've **ever** seen the multiple-object using-statement used "in the wild".

Comment: @MarcGravell: Likewise; it's pretty rare - but I suspect `Stream` is likely to be an almost canonical example... unless maybe you're iterating over two collections explicitly...

Comment: or maybe a `SqlBulkCopy` between two databases (two `SqlConnection` etc). Anyway, we digress.